# How to reuse screen in React Navigation which is easy to read and maintain?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My goal is to standardize to one practice for the `navigate()` method in React Navigation which is readable and maintainable React Navigation

My current practice is **hard to read, and maintain** if you use 2 different ReuseableComponents as a Screen, and these ReuseableComponents **have to decide where to navigate next.**

1. Home Screen -> `navigateTo ReuseableComponent A with params A or ReuseableComponent A with params B` -> `navigateTo ReuseableComponent B with params A or ReuseableComponent B with params B ?` screen -> `navigateTo InterCitySummary` / `WithInCitySummary ?` screen.

My current practice is easy to read and maintain for:

1. Home -> ReuseableComponent A -> UniqueScreen with defined `NextRoute`

This is how we do it using GoJek's UI. The repository: [gojek-clone](https://github.com/kidfrom/gojek_clone).

My current practice is to re-use `Screen` by leveraging the params, `navigate( 'route', { ...params } )`.

The idea is simple but hard to maintain `because if you change one component, most likely you have to change every components that depends on it.`:

1. params `navigateTo` decide where the screen should go next and params `nextRoute` decide where the screen should go next-next `in case the navigateTo screen is a ReuseableComponent and have more than 1 route to choose`.
2. if params `navigateTo` is undefined then passed params `nextRoute` is the `navigateTo` for the next Screen.
3. a ReuseableComponent can have own `navigateTo` and `nextRoute` state and other state to pass as a params for the `navigate()` method.

App.js

```
<Stack.Screen name="DestinationScreen" component={ReuseableComponent} />
<Stack.Screen name="PickUpScreen" component={ReuseableComponent} />
<Stack.Screen name="WithInCitySummary" component={WithinCitySummary} />
<Stack.Screen name="InterCitySummary" component={InterCitySummary} />
```

ReuseableComponent.js

```
export default function ReuseableComponent({
  route: { params },
  navigation: { navigate },
}) {
  const { navigateTo, nextRoute } = params; 

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() =>
        navigate(navigateTo, { 
          navigateTo: navigateTo ? navigateTo : nextRoute,
          nextRoute: nextRoute 
        })
      }
    >
      <Text>Next</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

What is your practice to write a readable and maintainable React Navigation?

Comment: This could lead to opinion based answers instead of fact based which the purpose of SO. If you have any problem or error with your code then please make it clear.

Comment: @SaachiTech I am beginning to search for set of practices when writing code since I see debugging and bug fixing as my job responsibility and asking in SO to fix my bug does not add value to myself. Do you have any suggestion where I could ask these kind of question?

Comment: I understand this is the sort of question that _could_ lead to opinion based answers, but at the same time there's no built in capacity for this functionality and every solution I've seen involves copying copious amounts of internal code from the NPM package, so I think asking for a workable pattern is reasonable and on topic.

Comment: @kidfrom - have you found a different solution approach? I'm also at the point in your question right now and I find it really difficult to maintain.

Comment: @RaideR sorry, I moved on to Android Native and iOS swift now.